# moving a row to another table but specific columns using active record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

What should be my model function structure if I delete an entire row from a table and insert two column values of the row to another table? I want to use active record.

```
function foo() 
{
    $this->db->truncate('to');
    $query = $this->db->get('from')->result(); // get first table
    foreach($query as $row)  // loop over results
    {
        $this->db->insert('to', $row); // insert each row to another table
    }
}
```

this is moving the entire row. I just want two specific column. What should I do?

**Edit**
Is it the right way?

```
public function refund() 
{   
   $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

   $data['accounts'] = $this->accounts_model->get_accounts_data_by_id($id);

   foreach ($accounts as $row)
   {     
        $data = array(
            'barcode' => $row->barcode,
            'refunded_amount' => $row->refunded_amount,
           );
    }

    $this->db-insert('refund',$data);
}
```

Comment: @AdrienXL take a look

Comment: seems that i have done it wrong. it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Inside the loop :

```
$insert = array(
               "column_name_1" => $row->wanted_column_1,
               "column_name_2" => $row->wanted_column_2
                );

$this->db->insert('to', $insert);
```

EDIT :

$accounts is not defined in your function.

try instead :

```
foreach ($data['accounts'] as $row)
{
     $data = array(
        'barcode' => $row->barcode,
        'refunded_amount' => $row->refunded_amount
        );

    $this->db->insert('refund',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Controller:**

```
class Controllername extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('your_model');
    }

    public function somename()
    {
       $id = 6;                                 // Row id to delete
       $this->your_model->delete_table1($id);

       $data = array(
                    array(
                     'col1' => 'val1',
                     'col2' => 'val2',
                     'col3' => 'val3',
                     ),
                    array(
                     'col1' => 'val1',
                     'col2' => 'val2',
                     'col3' => 'val3',
                     ),
                );
       $this->your_model->insert_table2($data);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class Your_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);
    }

    public function delete_table1($id)
    {
        $this->db->delete('table1', array('id' => $id));
    }

    public function insert_table2($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert_batch('table2', $data);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

1) Created a function in which you call a model function provided with the **`$id`** parameter of the row to be deleted from **`table1`**.
2) The second model function called inserts 2 rows to **`table2`** provided the array as argument and used **`insert_batch()`** active record functionality.
3) Before doing the above tasks, don't forget to **`load the model`** in the Controller constructer.